# JSTree DND Event at Drag Starting Point

Tags: jstree, drag-and-drop

I have a external draggable object (draggable implemented through jstee's dnd) on which I need to perform a check before the object starts dragging.

I'm looking for a method much like "drag_finish" or a binding I can use, but at the start of the dragging event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).bind("drag_start.vakata", function (e, data) { 
  if(data.data.jstree) { 
    // add your code here 
  } 
});
```

Binding to the document did the trick

Comment: any idea why this doesn't work on the drag_finish event? drag_start is pretty useless for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a more complete answer, here's some code for all 3 events (start, drag and stop):

```
$(document).bind("drag_start.vakata", function (e, data) {
    if (data.data.jstree) {
        //User started dragging
    }
});

$(document).bind("drag.vakata", function (e, data) {
    if (data.data.jstree) {
        //User is dragging
    }
});

$(document).bind("drag_stop.vakata", function (e, data) {
    if (data.data.jstree) {
       //User stopped dragging
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**drag_start.vakata** has been changed to **dnd_start.vakata** Now the above event would be triggered on these Functions:

```
$(document).bind("drag_start.vakata", function (e, data) {
if (data.data.jstree) {
    //User started dragging
}});

$(document).bind("drag.vakata", function (e, data) {
if (data.data.jstree) {
    //User is dragging
}});

$(document).bind("drag_stop.vakata", function (e, data) {
if (data.data.jstree) {
   //User stopped dragging
}});
```